# Is there a "trim" like method in java for integer loops?

Tags: java, loops, trim, removing-whitespace

I am printing a set of integers using a for loop, but I don't want the space at the very end after the last number. I noticed the String has something like trim, but I haven't been able to find a thread that talks about a trim like method for integers in a loop.

Here is very small snippet of my code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Enter the numbers you want in the array ");
        size[i] = scanner.nextInt();

    }

    min = size[0]; // I had to initialize this after the program knew how big the array would be

    for(int i = 0; i < size.length; i++){
        System.out.print(size[i] +  " ");
    }
```

Comment: Please include your source code in the question. 

You probably want to do

`String.valueOf(yourInteger).strip()`

Comment: What space at the end of number? If you just print them there's no space at the end. Share your code so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: I don't get the down votes on this question. Please add comments if you're down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make your print conditional:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size.length; i++){
    if(i == size.length -1){
       System.out.print(size[i]);
    } else {
       System.out.print(size[i] +  " ");
    }
}
```

However, I'd encourage use of the iterator syntax:

```
boolean first = true;
for(int val : size){
    if(first){
        System.out.print(val);
        first = false;
    } else {
        System.out.print(" " + val);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect. I am not used to iterator syntax. We haven't gone over it in class, but hopefully soon. Thanks!

Comment: I like to use it because it helps me avoid list iteration mistakes, and it means I don't have to have integers called 'i' and 'j' all over my code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String output = "";
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    output += i + " ";
}
System.out.println(output.trim());
```

Comment: It's much faster to build up a string in a StringBuilder or a StringBuffer. The compiler will do it for you when doing it all in a single expression, but not across multiple statements.

Comment: @Jerry101 I agree, but I used string concatenation for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Good point. A programming beginner is better off learning such details later.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend the Tyler's and hermitmaster's solution but if you have no issues with space , you can create a new String and keep on concatenating the integers and use trim() method to get rid of leading and trailing white space, and print it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size.length; i++){

    System.out.print("Enter the numbers you want in the array ");
    size[i] = scanner.nextInt();

}

min = size[0];

String result = ""; // temporary variable to store integers.

for(int i = 0; i < size.length; i++){
    result += size[i] +  " "; // concatenate integers to string
}
System.out.println(result.trim()); // removes leading and trailing white space.
```